# A-Frame setting attributes for text

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to create a text entity with the following attributes so that I don't have to specify these details every time I use text

```
  text.setAttribute('color', #303030);
  text.setAttribute('width', 2);
  text.setAttribute('lineHeight', 60);
  text.setAttribute('align', 'center');
  text.setAttribute('baseline', 'top');
  text.setAttribute('wrapcount', 12);
```

but I don't really understand how 'schema' and 'AFRAME.registerComponent' work. can someone please help with how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in [mixins](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/core/mixins.html#sidebar) which is another form of creating a reusable template:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <!-- define the template -->
    <a-mixin id="red" material="color: red"></a-mixin>
  </a-assets>
  <!-- use the template -->
  <a-box mixin="red"></a-box >
</a-scene>
```

In your case, it could be a simple `text` mixin with all common attributes:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("text-creator", {
    init: function() {
      var messages = ["one", "two", "three"]
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // create an <a-entity>
        var txt = document.createElement('a-entity')
        // use the mixin
        txt.setAttribute("mixin", "text")
        // set the text value
        txt.setAttribute("text", "value", messages[i])
        txt.setAttribute("position", -0.25 + i + " 2 -2")
        this.el.appendChild(txt)
      }
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene text-creator>
  <a-assets>
    <a-mixin id="text" text="color: blue; width: 2, lineHeight: 60, align: center, baseline: top, wrapcount: 12"></a-mixin>
  </a-assets>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
</a-scene>
```

[`AFRAME.registerComponent(<name>, <body>)`](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#sidebar) is just a form of saying "I want to have the `<body>` functionality when i attach the `<name>` component to an entity".

The schema is just a declaration of the component's properites. Try to follow the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#sidebar) and write your own component and feel free to post a question once it behaves in a weird way.